# How to preserve development datastore from clearing itself on reboot

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I need to change my local datastore path of APP Engine. I have followed methods specified here [How can I persist the local datastore for GoogleAppEngineLauncher between reboots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547087/how-can-i-persist-the-local-datastore-for-googleappenginelauncher-between-reboot) . I tried changing datastore path but it didn't work. I am using App Engine SDK 1.6.4, Python 2.7 and NDB as datastore on Windows 7. Also I could not find default datastore location on my computer as stated in dev_appserver.py -help output (which is a temp location but I searched while application was running and datastore was serving).

My objective is to stop local datastore cleaning itself on each launch (I am using launcher).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I persist the local datastore for GoogleAppEngineLauncher between reboots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547087/how-can-i-persist-the-local-datastore-for-googleappenginelauncher-between-reboot)

Answer (score 2):

The datastore SHOULD persist between reboots.

When you shut down, the server you should see a message "Applying all pending transactions and saving the datastore" in the console.  If not, you maybe seeing the following issue (two questions, same issue, first one has a workaround)

[GAE SDK 1.6.4 dev_appserver datastore flush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060172/gae-sdk-1-6-4-dev-appserver-datastore-flush)

[App Engine local datastore content does not persist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047315/app-engine-local-datastore-content-does-not-persist)